# XPath select ancestor / decendant tree from element to element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I currently have an xml document which looks like this:

```
<site>
  <body>
    <group name="content">
      <Categories>
        <item id="1" name="cat1">
          <Children>
            <item id="2" name="cat2">
              <Children>
                <item id="3" name="cat3">
                  <Children>
                    <item id="4" name="cat4" />
                  </Children>
                </item>
                <item id="5" name="cat5">
                  <Children>
                    <item id="6" name="cat6" />
                    <item id="7" name="cat7" />
                    <item id="8" name="cat8" />
                  </Children>
                </item>
                <item id="9" name="cat9" />
                <item id="10" name="cat10" />
              </Children>
            </item>
          </Children>
        </item>
      </Categories>
    </group>
  </body>
</site>
```

If a user has selected a category with id=3:

How can I [in my xsl stylesheet], select all the descendants from the root Categories element to the selected element, and iterate through them ?   Maybe something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Categories//*[@id=3 and ancestor::Categories[1]]"> . .   ?
```

Leaving me to then just:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@name" /> >
```

Resulting in:

```
cat1 > cat2 > cat3 >
```

Please let me know if further clarification is needed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="item[@id=3]">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="ancestors"
    select="ancestor-or-self::item"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="ancestors">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"> > </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<site>
  <body>
    <group name="content">
      <Categories>
        <item id="1" name="cat1">
          <Children>
            <item id="2" name="cat2">
              <Children>
                <item id="3" name="cat3">
                  <Children>
                    <item id="4" name="cat4" />
                  </Children>
                </item>
                <item id="5" name="cat5">
                  <Children>
                    <item id="6" name="cat6" />
                    <item id="7" name="cat7" />
                    <item id="8" name="cat8" />
                  </Children>
                </item>
                <item id="9" name="cat9" />
                <item id="10" name="cat10" />
              </Children>
            </item>
          </Children>
        </item>
      </Categories>
    </group>
  </body>
</site>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
cat1 > cat2 > cat3
```

---

**Update**:

In a comment the OP asks:

> how can I dynamically set the `'id'` value on the
>   `match="item[@id=3]". .` so that instead of having a line saying
>   `<xsl:template match="item[@id=3]"> . .` I could have one saying
>   `<xsl:template match="item[@id=$param]">`

Assuming that you have a global parameter `$pId` that contains the wanted value

**In XSLT 2.0 just modify the `xsl:template` from:**

```
 <xsl:template match="item[@id=3]">
```

**to**:

```
 <xsl:template match="item[@id=$pId]">
```

**In XSLT 1.0 it isn't allowed to have a variable/parameter reference within a match pattern**.
Below is an XSLT 1.0 solution that covers the new requirement:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pId" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="ancestors"
    select="self::*[@id=$pId]/ancestor-or-self::item"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(current()/@id = $pId)]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="ancestors">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"> > </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Of course, this solution doesn't look for a Categories element. Given the sample data, it doesn't need to. But given the way the question was phrased, I wonder if the Categories element is actually supposed to play a role?

Comment: @MichaelKay, Good observation. I don't know -- there is `Categories` but there is no `Category` element. The transformation will need to be modified in case there were `Category` elements and especially in the case where nested categories were allowed.

Comment: Hi Dimitre thanks for the reply. I've tried it and it does indeed work like a charm, however, how can I dynamically set the 'id' value on the  match="item[@id=3]". .  so that instead of having a line saying `<xsl:template match="item[@id=3]">`  . . I could have one saying `<xsl:template match="item[@id=$param]">` ?

Comment: Wow. Dimitre. Thank you. An incredible answer. I wish I could give you feedback but I don't have enough reputation points. But thank you for your help, I'm sure it will also help others searching for this issue aswell.